# In Selenium, how to compare images?

Tags: image, selenium, comparison

As i have been asked to automate our Company's website using Selenium Automation tooL.
But i am new to Selenium tool to proceed with, but i have learnt the basics of Selenium IDE and RC. But i am very much confused with how to compare actual and original images as we usually do in other automation tools. How do we come to a result that there bug in the website? Its obviously through image comparison but i wonder as selenium is one of the very popular tools but it doesn't have image comparing option. On the other hand i doubt whether my way of proceeding with the automation process is correct! Could somebody please help me out..

Thanks in Advance!!
Sanjay S

Answer (score 2):

I had simillar task. I needed to compare more than 3000 images on a WebPage.
First of all I scrolled page to load all images:

```
public void compareImage() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    Long previousHeight;
    Long currentHeight;

    do {
       previousHeight = (Long) executor.executeScript("return                document.documentElement.scrollHeight");

        executor.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight)");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        currentHeight = (Long) executor.executeScript("return        document.documentElement.scrollHeight");
    } while (Long.compare(previousHeight, currentHeight) != 0);
```

after I compared size of all images with first image(or you can just write size):

```
List<WebElement> images = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[class='playable']"));
    List<String> errors = new LinkedList<>();

    int imgWidth, imgHeight, elWidth, elHeight;
    int imgNum = 0;

    imgWidth = images.get(0).getSize().getWidth();
    imgHeight = images.get(0).getSize().getHeight();


    for (WebElement el : images) {
        imgNum++;

        elWidth = el.getSize().getWidth();
        elHeight = el.getSize().getHeight();

        if (imgWidth != elWidth || imgHeight != elHeight) {
            errors.add(String.format("Picture # %d has incorrect size (%d : %d) px"
                    , imgNum, elWidth, elHeight));
        }
    }

    for (String str : errors)
        System.out.println(str);

    if (errors.size() == 0)
        System.out.println("All images have the same size");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention knowledge about Selenium RC, you can easily extend Selenium's capability using a library for your chosen programming language. For instance, in Java you can use the [PixelGrabber](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html) class for comparing two images and assert their match.

Comment: As i use Selenium RC for the Programming language C#. I feel difficult on comparing the original and the output images. Using tools like ImageMagick or ImageDiff performs image comparison but it does its work only for one set of image at a time.. As i have more than 500 set of images, its quite a difficult task to perform image comparison. Is there any other method to solve this like to compare many set of images at a time rather comparing one by one as its time consuming. Can it be done using web driver >?

Thanks in Advance.. Sanjay ..

Answer (score 0):

imagemagick and imagediff are also two good tools to use for image matching. You would require Selenium RC and a programming language knowledge to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Image comparison on C#. To get exact results I recommend to disable anti aliasing browser feature before taking screenshots, otherwise pixels each time are a little bit different drawn. For example HTML canvas element options.AddArgument("disable-canvas-aa");

```
private static bool ImageCompare(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, Double TolerasnceInPercent)
    {
        bool equals = true;
        bool flag = true;  //Inner loop isn't broken

        //Test to see if we have the same size of image
        if (bmp1.Size == bmp2.Size)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmp1.Width; ++x)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < bmp1.Height; ++y)
                {
                    Color Bitmap1 = bmp1.GetPixel(x, y);
                    Color Bitmap2 = bmp2.GetPixel(x, y);

                    if (Bitmap1.A != Bitmap2.A)
                    {
                        if (!CalculateTolerance(Bitmap1.A, Bitmap2.A, TolerasnceInPercent))
                        {
                            flag = false;
                            equals = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (Bitmap1.R != Bitmap2.R)
                    {
                        if (!CalculateTolerance(Bitmap1.R, Bitmap2.R, TolerasnceInPercent))
                        {
                            flag = false;
                            equals = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (Bitmap1.G != Bitmap2.G)
                    {
                        if (!CalculateTolerance(Bitmap1.G, Bitmap2.G, TolerasnceInPercent))
                        {
                            flag = false;
                            equals = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (Bitmap1.B != Bitmap2.B)
                    {
                        if (!CalculateTolerance(Bitmap1.B, Bitmap2.B, TolerasnceInPercent))
                        {
                            flag = false;
                            equals = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                if (!flag)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            equals = false;
        }
        return equals;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This C# function calculates tolerance

```
private static bool CalculateTolerance(Byte FirstImagePixel, Byte SecondImagePixel, Double TolerasnceInPercent)
    {
        double OneHundredPercent;
        double DifferencesInPix;
        double DifferencesPercentage;


        if (FirstImagePixel > SecondImagePixel)
        {
            OneHundredPercent = FirstImagePixel;
        }
        else
        {
            OneHundredPercent = SecondImagePixel;
        }

        if (FirstImagePixel > SecondImagePixel)
        {
            DifferencesInPix = FirstImagePixel - SecondImagePixel;
        }
        else
        {
            DifferencesInPix = SecondImagePixel - FirstImagePixel;
        }

        DifferencesPercentage = (DifferencesInPix * 100) / OneHundredPercent;

        DifferencesPercentage = Math.Round(DifferencesPercentage, 2);

        if (DifferencesPercentage > TolerasnceInPercent)
        {
            return false;                
        }

        return true;
    }
```